# Import module from node_modules (create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, import, create-react-app

How do I import modules from outside src directory?

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui' in '/Users/suvo/GitHub/portfolio/src'
```

According to `react-material-icons` page, I was supposed to import as follows:

```
import mui from 'material-ui';
```

the error's strange. i got `import $ from 'jquery';` just next to `import mui...` and it works fine. What's more, if i create a new project and add 
react-material-icons, the npm won't start, showing an error:

```
> myapp@0.1.0 start /Users/suvo/GitHub/myapp
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! myapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/suvo/.npm/_logs/2017-09-11T11_40_15_791Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `.` in front of the package name.

```
import mui from 'material-ui';
```

Packages you install using `npm install` or `yarn install` are saved to `node_modules` directory. You can import them by just specifying package name.

```
import React from 'react';
import mui from 'material-ui';

import AlarmIcon from 'react-material-icons/icons/action/alarm';

export default class Alarm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AlarmIcon/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: still i got error:
Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui' in '/Users/suvo/GitHub/portfolio/src'

Comment: got no idea where i had this dot from, i updated the question with actual error

Comment: can you try doing `yarn install react-material-icons` or `npm install --save react-material-icons` again and try?

Comment: i tried, still the same error. And if i create a new project with create-react-app and install react-material-icons there, i get another error (see updated question)

Comment: I'm facing this issue as well, I found a solution, unfortunately, it didn't work for me, but I heard that webpack needs to know where to look for the modules. To do this, edit `./App/webpack.config.js` with the following content: 

    module.exports = {
     resolve: {
      modules: [
       "../node_modules/"
      ]
     }
    };

Make sure of course that the module is installed in the `node_modules` folder. Hope this works for you.